# How to copy windows live mail settings to new profile

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, windows-live-mail, windows-domain

I've just set up a server as a Windows 2008 R2 domain controller and have configured my Windows 7 PC to be part of the domain.

Now that I got a new user profile, how do I migrate settings like Windows Live Mail to the new profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best solution is to export your email, accounts and contacts when you are logged into the old user account, save them to a folder of choice, log into the new account and Import them back into Live Mail.

http://liveunplugged.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/how-to-backup-windows-live-mail-accounts-contacts-and-messages/

.

Comment: How about the feeds?

Comment: When you export messages, Feeds are included if you select them.